# DataList Question

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

I have the following databound `DataList` inside an `UpdatePanel` which updates whenever a selection is made from a `DropDown` menu.
However, if nothing is retrieved from the db table, I get a blank section.

What I would like to do is display the same table which is inside the `ItemTemplate` along with text - i.e. 'Admin Not Found', 'Email Not Found'....etc for the EmptyDataTempate...
I've noticed that the `EmptyDataTemplate` doesn't exist for a DataList, but I don't want to use a different control.

Is there a way to do this? Sample code appreciated. Thanks!

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="style1">
                    Company Admin:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Eval("CompanyAdmin") %>' CssClass="input input1" ID="co_admin"
                        Width="150" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Admin Email:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Eval("AdminEmail") %>' CssClass="input input1" ID="ad_email"
                        Width="150" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Company Email:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Eval("CompanyEmail") %>' CssClass="input input1" ID="co_email"
                        Width="150" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Telephone:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Eval("Telephone") %>' CssClass="input input1" ID="telephone"
                        Width="150" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a simple function that return a msg if the field is null.

You call a function like

```
<%#GetWithMsg(Container.DataItem, "CompanyEmail", "e-mail n/a")%>
```

for example

```
 <asp:TextBox Text='<%# GetWithMsg(Container.DataItem, "CompanyEmail", "e-mail n/a") %>' CssClass="input input1" ID="co_email"
                    Width="150" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" />
```

and the code behind.

```
protected string GetWithMsg(object oItem, string cField, string TheMsg)
{
    var TheData = DataBinder.Eval(oItem, cField);

    if(TheData == null)
        return TheMsg;
    else
        return TheData.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I tried to add your code and it's not making a difference for some reason :( It's still retrieving the values, but not displaying a string when null. What could be causing this? I am using an updatepanel, so do I need to add any code in the selectedindexchange od the dropdown when the binding occurs?

Comment: @user618616 maybe is not null but is empty, check also if ToString().Lenght == 0  ( also you can use the string.IsNullOrEmpty()

Comment: Hmm...still not displaying the messages.

Comment: the above code looks good, maybe you need to force an update on that UpdatePanel (depending on how you'he set your hierarchy of controls). Try a mYUpdatePanel.Update() .

Answer (score 0):

not tested but mybe you can try

```
'<%# !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("CompanyEmail").ToString()) ? Eval("CompanyEmail") : "Email Not Found" %>'
```

explicit casting might be better in terms of performance than eval though
e.g.

```
'<%# !string.IsNullOrEmpty(((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["CompanyEmail"].ToString()) ? ((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["CompanyEmail"].ToString() : "Email Not Found" %>'
```

hope itll help

Sample Edit:

```
protected void BindData()
{
    DataTable dt = DAL.GetData(...
    if(dt.Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow());
    }
    DataList.DataSource = dt;
    DataList.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Nothing's working for some reason...is there any other way you can think of doing this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: sorry, didnt notice this statement "However, if nothing is retrieved from the db table, I get a blank section", this means we dont bind any data, just test the datatable before binding and add an empty row if needed, e.g. if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
         {dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow());}